# Can't compile java project on intelij Idea 14 CE

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-14

About a week from now i started using Intelij Idea 14 Community Edition  on OS X 10.10 without any significant problem and since this morning i get this error when i try to compile or run my last java project :

> Error:java: Internal error: 
>   java.io.EOFException
>       at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:267)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.builders.java.dependencyView.TypeRepr$1.read(TypeRepr.java:295)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.builders.java.dependencyView.TypeRepr$1.read(TypeRepr.java:282)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.builders.java.dependencyView.TypeRepr$ClassType.(TypeRepr.java:190)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.builders.java.dependencyView.TypeRepr$1.read(TypeRepr.java:302)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.builders.java.dependencyView.TypeRepr$1.read(TypeRepr.java:282)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.builders.java.dependencyView.TypeRepr$ClassType.(TypeRepr.java:190)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.builders.java.dependencyView.TypeRepr$1.read(TypeRepr.java:302)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.builders.java.dependencyView.TypeRepr$1.read(TypeRepr.java:282)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.builders.java.dependencyView.TypeRepr$ClassType.(TypeRepr.java:190)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.builders.java.dependencyView.TypeRepr$1.read(TypeRepr.java:302)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.builders.java.dependencyView.TypeRepr$1.read(TypeRepr.java:282)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.builders.java.dependencyView.TypeRepr$ClassType.(TypeRepr.java:190)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.builders.java.dependencyView.TypeRepr$1.read(TypeRepr.java:302)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.builders.java.dependencyView.TypeRepr$1.read(TypeRepr.java:282)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.builders.java.dependencyView.ClassRepr.(ClassRepr.java:257)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.builders.java.dependencyView.ClassRepr$2.read(ClassRepr.java:389)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.builders.java.dependencyView.ClassRepr$2.read(ClassRepr.java:381)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.builders.java.dependencyView.ObjectObjectPersistentMultiMaplet$CollectionDataExternalizer.read(ObjectObjectPersistentMultiMaplet.java:259)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.builders.java.dependencyView.ObjectObjectPersistentMultiMaplet$CollectionDataExternalizer.read(ObjectObjectPersistentMultiMaplet.java:237)
>       at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.doGet(PersistentHashMap.java:518)
>       at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.get(PersistentHashMap.java:451)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.builders.java.dependencyView.ObjectObjectPersistentMultiMaplet$1.createValue(ObjectObjectPersistentMultiMaplet.java:53)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.builders.java.dependencyView.ObjectObjectPersistentMultiMaplet$1.createValue(ObjectObjectPersistentMultiMaplet.java:48)
>       at com.intellij.util.containers.SLRUCache.get(SLRUCache.java:46)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.builders.java.dependencyView.ObjectObjectPersistentMultiMaplet.get(ObjectObjectPersistentMultiMaplet.java:76)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.builders.java.dependencyView.Mappings$Differential.differentiate(Mappings.java:1985)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.builders.java.dependencyView.Mappings.differentiateOnIncrementalMake(Mappings.java:2038)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.builders.java.JavaBuilderUtil.updateMappings(JavaBuilderUtil.java:99)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.compile(JavaBuilder.java:326)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.doBuild(JavaBuilder.java:204)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.build(JavaBuilder.java:176)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runModuleLevelBuilders(IncProjectBuilder.java:1140)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuildersForChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:826)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTargetsChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:894)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunkIfAffected(IncProjectBuilder.java:789)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunks(IncProjectBuilder.java:612)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:352)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:191)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:131)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:229)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:113)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler$1.run(BuildMain.java:158)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl$1.run(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:41)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Thank you.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

- In menu "Build > Rebuild project".
- In menu "File > Invalidate caches / Restart... > Invalidate and Restart".
- Remove last installed/enabled plugins if any.
- Check dependencies (especially cyclic-dependencies) in "File > Project Structure... > Modules"
- The last chance: make backup & remove .idea folder from your project directory and create new project from scratch.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it didn't solve the problem, i still have the same error.

Comment: After removing the .idea folder and creating a new project it worked fine, thank you !

Comment: i have the same problem, tried all your suggestions and still not working =/

Comment: i got the same issue couldn't resolve. tried everything

Answer (score 28):

- In menu "Build > Rebuild project".

Comment: I came to this page because of Groovy compile error, and rebuild was enough to get things into normal state.

Comment: This is the answer. Accepted answer is basically "Idk the answer, try all these blanket-solutions". Your answer is so on-point, OP edited his answer to include your suggestion as his first suggestion, a whole 2 years after you posted the answer.

Answer (score 4):

It is simple,
You have the following options:

1. Goto menu option "Build" -> "Rebuild project"
2. Goto menu "File" -> "Invalidate caches / Restart..." -> "Invalidate and Restart".

Answer (score 1):

I tried above methods but none worked. Finally I resolved it by refreshing the maven dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I tried every way mentioned above but this compilation error still appeared, it did't come out again until i turn off the "shadowsocks" on my mac.

Answer (score 0):

I exit and relaunch intelliJ and deleted out folder, and it started working
[image]