# Intellij Idea java Build Failed production: java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: java, intellij-idea, build

When I tried to **Run** a `.java` file during the **build** I got the following ***Error***

> *Module 'JAVA-Workspace' production: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.jetbrains.jps.builders.java.dependencyView.TypeRepr$PrimitiveType cannot be cast to class org.jetbrains.jps.builders.java.dependencyView.TypeRepr$ClassType (org.jetbrains.jps.builders.java.dependencyView.TypeRepr$PrimitiveType and org.jetbrains.jps.builders.java.dependencyView.TypeRepr$ClassType are in unnamed module of loader java.net.URLClassLoader @490d6c15)*

'JAVA-Workspace' is my project directory.
It was fine a few minutes ago I was debugging the same file.
I did not install any new plugins at the time.
**Java 11** | [image: Intellj Version]

I tried :

- Remove caches and indexes by `Invalidate and Restart` **<** `Invalidate Caches` **<** `File`.
- Delete `.idea` in root directory of the project.

Thank You

Comment: Check if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64336525/how-do-i-fix-an-error-in-intellij-that-prevents-me-from-running-my-projects

Comment: @pringi I saw that thread. Noting working for him too. He replied wait for the next update . . .

Comment: What version of Intellij, what version of java? Try also to run from command line and check the errors you obtain. I think the problem will be related with Java modules. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67782975/how-to-fix-the-module-java-base-does-not-opens-java-io-to-unnamed-module

Comment: Have you tried creating a new project with just your source code to see if that builds? Or reinstalling IntelliJ?

Comment: not i have not tried to re-install yet . . . I want to understand the error too. I will do if nothing works.

Comment: @abhinit21 did you manage to find out what the issue was or how to fix it? Same thing happened to me, was working fine and suddenly this without any changes.

Comment: @Mr.O in my case I have deleted the build output folder "target" and then re-build the project solved the issue

I have got help from -> intellj https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-289413/Build-Failed-While-saving-caches-Java-11

Answer (score 3):

I have this problem recently. My solution is that find out the most possible file produce this error, such as the most recent edit file (such as xxx.java). The files have to be guessed. Copy a backup of the code and delete that file. Then try to compile again, (of course cancel or comment the other linkages to that file) until the project can be compiled. Then re-new the java files with same name and same code just deleted before. The project will be as same as before. Finally, it compiles normally.